# Sort meta data from xml export plguin

Tags: xml, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to sort the xml data that is exported by the Woocommerce plugin `WooCommerce Customer/Order XML Export Suite`?

I have some meta tags that are being exported but these are always showing up at the bottom of the xml file. Is it possible to re-position them?

This is how they look in the plugin:

[image]

This is the XML that is exported:

[image]

Notice the meta tags sent to bottom.